# How to pass a Map object to a RestController method?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have an API method like below inside my RestController

```
@PostMapping("/asd")
public ResponseEntity<String> asd(@RequestBody MyParams params) { ... }
```

`MyParams` class is like below.

```
public class MyParams implements Serializable {
  public List<Long> ids;
  public List<String> ignoredTypes;
  public Map<String, List<String>> aMapping;
}
```

In postman, I pass a JSON string like

```
{
    "ids": [28712, 344248],
    "ignoredTypes": [],
    "aMapping": "{\"Person\":[\"name\",\"age\"],\"Title\":[\"start\",\"end\"]}",
}
```

I get an error saying

> 2021-08-16 18:25:53.953  WARN 4164 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
> `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no
> String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String
> value ('{"Person":["name","age"],"Title":["start","end"]}'); nested
> exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one
> Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value
> ('{"Person":["name","age"],"Title":["start","end"]}')  at [Source:
> (PushbackInputStream); line: 12, column: 20] (through reference chain:
> com.xyz.MyParams["aMapping"])]

So basically `java.util.Map` cannot be parsed from JSON string. How can I do that?

Comment: you are passig string for aMapping. you have to pass json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried like this

```json
{
  "prop1": [1],
  "prop2": ["string"],
  "prop3": {
    "additionalProp1": [
      "string"
    ],
    "additionalProp2": [
      "string"
    ],
    "additionalProp3": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
}
```

Try to pass the JSON object as it is without stringifying

Answer (score 1):

I changed the request body and it worked.

```
{
  "ids": [
    28712,
    344248
  ],
  "ignoredTypes": [
    
  ],
  "aMapping": {
    "Person": [
      "name",
      "age"
    ],
    "Title": [
      "start",
      "end"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]